# Продукт относится к заказу MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать работу с двумя сущностями (таблицами) продукт и заказ в MySQL php.
Есть вариант смежных таблиц (третья таблица выводит что к чему относиться). Какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: А что тогда в таблице с заказами, если там нет ссылок на продукты? Дата и кто заказал?

Comment: В таблице у нас создатель заказа, название, id, дата и и.д. Так как у нас к одному заказу может относится 10 продуктов, и они могут удалятся и добавлятся к заказу.

Comment: вариант с третьей таблицей - нормализован

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связь один ко многим,  нужные таблицы продукты , заказ, продукт_заказ. Это самый идеальный вариант.